# Best way to update foreign keys to point to different table?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm doing some cleanup of a mysql database that has grown messy over time.  The cleanup is incremental (that is to say I don't want to migrate all of the tables at once).

My preference, wherever possible, is to avoid destructive editing of the old tables.  For example, I rename table folders to *decomissioned_folders* and then create a new *folders* table that the appropriate records can be migrated into, without affecting the old table.

There are a lot of tables in this database, one of which is table *users*.  Many other tables in the database have foreign keys that point to table *users*.

I am wondering:

If I rename table *users* to *decomissioned_users* and then create a new *users* table, and populate it, what is the best way to deal with the foreign keys?  For every table in the database that now contains foreign keys pointing to the old *decomissioned_users* table, is there a (simple) way to update those foreign keys to point to the new *users* table instead?

(Note, the value of the ids does not change between tables, so the values of the foreign keys will remain valid across tables.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a straightforward way, but it involves dropping the old foreign keys and creating new foreign keys.

Here's a demo:

```
mysql> create table foo (id serial primary key);

mysql> create table bar (foo_id bigint unsigned, foreign key (foo_id) references foo(id));
```

After we rename the table, the foreign key reference is automatically updated to follow the renamed table:

```
mysql> rename table foo to old_foo;

mysql> show create table bar\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: bar
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `bar` (
  `foo_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `foo_id` (`foo_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `bar_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`foo_id`) REFERENCES `old_foo` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

After we create a new table:

```
mysql> create table foo like old_foo;
```

We can redefine the foreign key in the following way:

```
mysql> alter table bar 
       drop foreign key bar_ibfk_1, 
       add foreign key (foo_id) references foo(id);
```

Now the table references the new table:

```
mysql> show create table bar\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: bar
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `bar` (
  `foo_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `foo_id` (`foo_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `bar_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`foo_id`) REFERENCES `foo` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

If you have many foreign keys, you can discover the list of them by querying the INFORMATION_SCHEMA, tables TABLE_CONSTRAINTS and KEY_COLUMN_USAGE. From this metadata you can build ALTER TABLE statements to change the foreign keys.

Comment: Thanks Bill, that's a great explanation!